# Как найти положительную подпоследовательность наибольшей длины?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, list

Не могу понять, как это сделать:
Запросить у пользователя размер массива. Задать длину динамического массива. Запросить и считать данные массива у пользователя. Дана последовательность чисел: `а1, а2, …, аN`. Найти положительную подпоследовательность наибольшей длины.

```py
a= int(input())
xyz=[]
for i in range (a):
    xyz.append(x)

dlina_xyz = len(xyz)

numbers= []
for i in range(a):
    1 =[]
    for j in range(i+1, a):
        if xyz[j]>0:
            1.append(xyz[j])
        else:
            numbers.append(1)
            break

print(numbers.sort(key=len)[0])
```

Я думаю, что ошибка в том, что у меня будет выводить не наибольшую длину.

Но как это сделать ?

Думаю, нужно получить все последовательности, проверить их на наличие отрицательных числел, и отсортировать по длине, выбирая максимально длинную.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте название языка в заголовок. Оно уже указано в метках

Comment: Хорошо, больше не буду

Comment: xyz.append(x) откуда берётся х ?  1 =[] вы число связали со списком ? зачем ?     добавляйте пожалуйсто полный текст ошибки

Comment: Пишет Unexpected indent
На xyz=[]

Comment: пробелы это важно в питоне.уберите лишние в этой строке

Comment: Выдает invalid syntax на 1.append(xyz[j])

Comment: Вам уже дважды написали - нельзя использовать числа в качестве имен переменных. назовите свой список не 1, а нормальным именем.

Answer (score 4):

Вариант решения со многими операторами `if`, но зато с алгоритмической сложностью `O(n)` (требуется один проход по списку), и расходом памяти `O(5)`:

```
def get_longest_pos_seq(arr):
    start_idx, stop_idx, max_len, counter, tmp = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i-1] <= 0 and arr[i] > 0:
            tmp = i
        if arr[i-1] > 0:
            if arr[i] > 0:
                counter += 1
            if arr[i] <= 0 or i == len(arr) - 1:
                if counter > max_len:
                    max_len = counter
                    start_idx = tmp
                    stop_idx = i + 1 if i == len(arr) - 1 else i
                counter = 0
    return arr[start_idx:stop_idx], start_idx, stop_idx
```

---

проверка:

```
In [61]: arr = [-5, 1, 2, -6, 2, 4, 5, -12, 2, 5, 6, 7]

In [62]: res, start_idx, stop_idx = get_longest_pos_seq(arr)

In [63]: res
Out[63]: [2, 5, 6, 7]

In [64]: start_idx
Out[64]: 8

In [65]: stop_idx
Out[65]: 12
```

Comment: Хорошая идея. Попробовал ее имплементировать  в свой код. Получилось -  см. выше. Правда -  пришлось заменить один for на while  и добавить один if. Думаю, можно было бы еще помудрить, но уже не так интересно.

Comment: @passant, мне было интересно решить эту задачу за `O(n)` ;)

Comment: И я Вас понимаю :-).

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы вам было не совсем скучно - ввод, создание и заполнение динамического массива, как тривиальнейшую задачу опускаю. Даю только поиск самой длинной последовательности положительных чисел. Вывожу искомую длину и номер индекса, с которого она начинается. На всякий случай.

```
max_len=0
for i in range(len(x)):
    c_len=0
    for j in range(i,len(x)):
        if x[j]>0:
            c_len=c_len+1
        else:
            break
    if c_len>max_len:
        max_len=c_len
        max_ind=i
print (max_len, max_ind)
```

Например, при `x=[0,1,2,3,-2,0,1,2,3,4,0,-1,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-3]`
имеем:

```
8 13
```

По мотивам [идей уважаемого @MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143538) о вычислительной сложности, внес некоторые модификации в первоначальную версию:

```
max_len=0
i=0
while i< len(x):
    print (i)
    c_len=0
    for j in range(i,len(x)):
        if x[j]>0:
            c_len=c_len+1
        else:
            break
    if c_len>max_len:
        max_len=c_len
        max_ind=i
    if c_len==0:
        i=i+1
    else:
        i=i+c_len
```

Результаты работы на моих данных:

```
8 13
```

Результат работы на примере @MaxU:

```
4 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def longest_pos_subarr(arr):
    res_length = 0
    res_start = 0

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        curr_length = 0
        curr_start = i

        while i < len(arr) and arr[i] > 0:
            curr_length += 1
            i += 1

        if curr_length > res_length:
            res_length = curr_length
            res_start = curr_start

    return (res_start, res_length)


arr = [-5, 1, 2, -6, 2, 4, 5, -12, 2, 5, 6, 7]

start, length = longest_pos_subarr(arr)

print(arr[start:start + length])
```

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта имеют алгоритмическую сложность `O(n)`.

**Вариант №1**

```
arr = [-5, 1, 2, -6, 2, 4, 5, -12, 2, 5, 6, 7]

max_subseq = []
tmp_subseq = []
for num in arr:
    if num > 0:
        tmp_subseq.append(num)
    else:
        max_subseq = max(max_subseq, tmp_subseq, key=len)
        tmp_subseq = []
# Дополнительная проверка нужна на случай, если
# последнее число положительное        
max_subseq = max(max_subseq, tmp_subseq, key=len)
print(max_subseq)
```

**Вариант №2**

Тоже самое можно записать короче в ущерб эффективности. Эффективность будет снижена по следующим причинам:

- `tmp_subseq + [num]` - на каждое положительное число создаётся список `[num]`, затем два списка объединяются.
- `max(max_subseq, tmp_subseq, key=len)` - каждый раз происходит сравнение длин списков.

```
arr = [-5, 1, 2, -6, 2, 4, 5, -12, 2, 5, 6, 7]

max_subseq = []
tmp_subseq = []
for num in arr:
    tmp_subseq = tmp_subseq + [num] if num > 0 else []
    max_subseq = max(max_subseq, tmp_subseq, key=len)

print(max_subseq)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: @MaxU Нет, она сравнивает два списка функцией `len()`, которая берёт длину у объекта. Проверять значения в списках функции `max()` не нужно.

Comment: Да, действительно - надо было мне внимательнее на код смотреть)

Comment: @MiniMax 1) Вопрос был про положительную подпоследовательность, а не неотрицательную; 2) Большое количество дополнительной памяти из-за пересоздавания листов

Comment: @вася 1) Согласен, надо поправить, чтобы не включало `0`. 2) Памяти в три раза больше в худшем случае. С одной стороны нехорошо, с другой надо смотреть по ситуации - насколько большие списки, насколько требуется экономить память. Но это решение больше про удобство и простоту кода, чем про производительность и экономию памяти.

Comment: @MiniMax в три раза больше, чем что? И как вы посчитали?

Comment: @вася В три раза больше, чем исходный список `arr`. Так как создаётся два дополнительных списка, которые в худшем случае, могут быть равны исходному списку `arr`. Например, если `arr` состоит только из положительных чисел: `arr = [1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: @MiniMax я скорее имел в виду, что списки могут постоянно пересоздаваться, т.е. лишние выделения памяти. Другими словами, лучше выделить память N раз на число, чем на пустой список

Comment: @вася В первом варианте не будут сильно пересоздаваться. `max_subseq` создаётся однократно. `tmp_subseq`, да, каждый раз при окончании положительной последовательности создаётся пустой список. Но на память это не влияет.

Comment: @MiniMax почему не влияет https://repl.it/repls/OpenUsableRobots?

Comment: @вася Новый создался, старый съел `garbage collector`. Итого, на всём протяжении работы программа имеет максимум три объекта `list`. А то что объект `list` крупнее объекта `int` это да. Но в данном случае несущественно.

Comment: @MiniMax откуда гарантия, что очистка произойдёт перед следующим созданием?

Comment: @вася Ну знаете ли :) Тогда уж можно добавить и то, что список это [Динамический массив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2) и при его увеличении периодически происходит перемещение на другой участок памяти. А это сказывается на производительности.